# Picasso cannot fetch jpg file link

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I have used Picasso library to fetch image but when it comes to the implementation, it retrieves nothing. Would you please me tell the expectational rule to deal with JPG images ?

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder , position: Int) {
    if (holder is VHItem) {
        val dataItem = getItem(position)
        holder.title!!.text = dataItem.name
        holder.desp!!.text = dataItem.district
        val arrayImage = dataItem.images

        if (arrayImage!!.isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.home_11_20_storage).into(holder.parentView);
        }
        else{
            val url = arrayImage[0]
            println("image url : ${url}" )
            Picasso.get().load(arrayImage[0]).resize(1800, 1800).centerInside().placeholder(R.drawable.home_11_20_storage)
                        .into(holder.parentView);
        }
        //cast holder to VHItem and set data
        } else if (holder is VHHeader) {
            //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
        }
    }
```

I/System.out: image url : http://www.spacecentrestorage.com/assets/uploads/General/SCS-Slide02-Commercial.jpg

Comment: does .get() is necessary

Comment: Is placeholder you assigned shown during loading?

Comment: Yes. We can see the placeholder

Comment: What is the problem indeed ?